# Padding issue in firefox when setting lang

Tags: css

This took me few hours to nail down the problem.  I am trying to center the span to vertical middle.  In Firefore, I see there are some padding bottom added to that.  And that's because I have set the lang to zh-hant in the body!  See below code snippet for demo.  Anyone know how to fix this?

```css
span {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
  <span lang="zh-hant">123456ABC</span>&nbsp;<span>123456ABC</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by adding `display: inline-block`, `overflow-hidden` and a fixed line-height (doesn't have to be a pixel value) to your css:

```css
span {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
  <span lang="zh-hant">123456ABC</span>&nbsp;<span>123456ABC</span>
```